Service Worker parameters without URL
Is there a way to pass values to a service worker without altering its script URL?
const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register("/sw.js?version=" + version, {
    scope: '/',
    type: 'module',
});

I feel like a dynamic string is not a good solution, since sw.js URL string should stay static.
IndexedDB? postMessage is not an option for cache versioning since I need this to work with all events.

That depends on what the server side will do (how it responds to the request), but you can just erase the query string if the sw.js is always the same: .register("/sw.js", { scope: '/', type: 'module'});.

@KLASANGUI But thats the only way to pass parameters.

It is not. You can always use registration.ready.then(controller => controller.postMessage({version})). Then you get the parameter in the service worker through the message event of the serviceWorker inside the sw.js script.

Its the only way to pass parameters to all events, not just message.

ServiceWorker have very few events. They're message, messagerror and controllerchange on the controller and error and statechange on the ServiceWorker object itself. So, there's only the message event that is useful to you.

That is absolutely wrong. install, fetch, message, activate, sync, push are service worker events. You need to read this

I'm not wrong. Those are ServiceWorkerGlobalScope events... What I sald was about the ServiceWorker which is a very different type. ServiceWorkerGlobalScope is unrelated to the question because it is in the sw.js context (which is brand new and separated from main.js). "this is basically a special kind of worker context, running off the main script execution thread, with no DOM access" in the Basic architecture section. item 1. In other words, those events are unrelated to your main.js context, which is the context that is sending the parameters to sw.js.

You can also use IndexedDB to share data with service worker that is persistent between suspending and running the service Worker. I suggest using IDB-Keyval library.

@jcubic yep, I feel like this is the last option, but it feels a bit overkill for a simple precache list.

You can use indexDB directly

EDIT: Here's what you really want (I think). Please, try to make yourself clear when asking questions. It was very hard to understand what you really need.
There's no other way besides postMessage() to achieve what you want.
main.js
const worker = navigator.serviceWorker.register
(
  'sw.js',
  {
    scope: '/',
    type: 'module',
  }
);
worker.addEventListener
(
   'message', message =>
   {
      // Retrieve data sent back from your
      // `ServiceWorkerContainer` instance.
      console.log('Data retrieved from `sw.js`:', message);
   }
);

sw.js
// Special case.
addEventListener
(
   'message', message =>
   {
      // You're receiving a message from `main.js`.
      // Should send data about this back?
      
      // I'm doing nothing with it. But you can, like
      // receiving the parameters from `main.js` and
      // storing them somewhere to configure your
      // `sw.js` context dynamically.
   }
);

// Listening to other relevant events...
for ( const event of ['activate', 'fetch', 'install', 'push', 'sync'] )
{
   addEventListener
   (
      event, eventData =>
      {
         // Note that `eventData` may differ depending on `event`.
         // You may write one listener for each event.
         
         const target = eventData.target;
         
         // Send the relevant data back to `main.js`.
         postMessage
         ({
            // The object constructor's name or the data if possible.
            eventData: target?.constructor.name ?? target ?? eventData,
            
            // The type of the event listened.
            eventType: eventData.type,
            
            // Send the enumerable properties of the event target back.
            eventResource: { ... Object(target) },
         });
      }
   );
}

NOTE: The eventResource in the returning data from sw.js is an object with the enumerable properties of the event target, if any, or the target itself, if truthy or the intercepted event data if possible. You can change what you send back to fit your needs.
Here's my previous suggestions:
1. To send data to your sw.js context, you just need the ServiceWorker.postMessage() instance method.
main.js
const worker = navigator.serviceWorker.register
(
  'sw.js',
  {
    scope: '/',
    type: 'module',
  }
);

worker.ready.then
(
  controller =>
  {
    controller.postMessage({parameter: 'value'});
  }
);

sw.js
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener
(
  'message', message =>
  {
    // message should contain:
    // { parameter: 'value' }
  }
);

2. If you want to intercept what is sent to sw.js, you use something like the snippet below:
main.js
const worker = navigator.serviceWorker.register
(
  'sw.js',
  {
    scope: '/',
    type: 'module',
  }
);

// Anything here will replace any data sent
const customData =
{
  source: import.meta.url,
}

// postMessage injection:

const nativePostMessage = worker.controller.postMessage.bind(worker.controller);

worker.controller.postMessage = customPostMessage;

function customPostMessage ( originalData, ...Arguments )
{
  const newData = 
  (
    ( typeof originalData == 'object' )
    ? {...originalData, ...customData, originalData}
    : Object.assign(Object(originalData), {...customData, originalData})
  );
  
  return nativePostMessage(newData, ...Arguments);
}

// TEST
worker.ready.then
(
  controller =>
  {
    controller.postMessage({greetings: 'Hello world.'});
  }
);

sw.js
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener
(
  'message', message =>
  {
    // message should contain:
    // { source: ..., greetings: ..., originalData: { greetings: ... } }
  }
);


As stated above, postMessage is not an option since I need this value in all events.

@charlie137 I slightly changed the script to inject data to be sent everytime a postMessage is called.

Once again, this is valid only for message event. I don’t need postMessage, its only good for pre-cache in my case. I need a solution that will work in ALL events

The custom data will change over time? Or it is always the same while sw.js is running? Because if it is the latter, then you only need to send that data once through postMessage() first and keep it in memory (referenced in some variable) at sw.js context. Then, sw.js will always have that data at every event that is fired in it after.

@charlie137 ServiceWorker have very few events. They're message, messagerror and controllerchange on the controller and error and statechange on the ServiceWorker object itself. So, there's only the message event that is useful to you.

No. Read the docs.

@charlie137 I'm not wrong. Those are ServiceWorkerGlobalScope events... What I sald was about the ServiceWorker which is a very different type. ServiceWorkerGlobalScope is unrelated to the question because it is in the sw.js context (which is brand new and separated from main.js). "this is basically a special kind of worker context, running off the main script execution thread, with no DOM access" in the Basic architecture section. item 1. In other words, those events are unrelated to your main.js context, which is the context that is sending the parameters to sw.js.

@charlie137 See, your question is on how to send parameters to the sw.js context without using the GET method query string, not what sw.js is doing with it, nor how to let main.js know what sw.js is doing. I'm losing reputation here all the while my answer is right. It's very unpleasant.

It also states no postMessage that you suggesting since it does not cover other events where I need its data.

@charlie137 Oh, I noticed that. But still, this restriction makes no sense considering the question asked. So I'm blatantly ignoring that. There's ONLY ONE way to send data to your ServiceWorker without using the http GET method's query string. And that's using the postMessage() method. I'll say this: if you want to observe those others events that happens in sw.js, your question is wrong. You should just accept this answer, that is right for your question, and open another one asking "how main.js could know the data in ServiceWorker events fired in the sw.js context".

@charlie137 By the way, you could achieve what you want just adding listeners to all those events at sw.js that use a postMessage() to send the event relevant data back to main.js, then make main.js listen to the message event and retrieve the data sent back from sw.js. But again, this is what you really want, but it's not the answer to the question you asked. See, postMessage() is inevitable.

Then the answer to the question would be “there is no other way”.

I'm editing the answer to resolve the issue you want. Just wait a bit and your problem should be solved.

@charlie137 I think it's good enough now. Please, tell me if I misunderstood something.

I needed a solution that is not touching postMessage, it is clearly stated in the question. IDK why you doing all this, theres already enough answers on service worker messages.

@charlie137 Why postMessage can't be touched? If not using it, you'll clog your thread (possibly the main or even both) racing over an indexedDB table parsing what sw.js inserts there and deleting the stuff your thread already parsed (even if it is intervalled). This is the only other, yet indirect, way to hardly do what you need and the performance will take a huge loss.
